# JavaScript / jQuery decode BBCode to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

Есть функция перевода BBCode в HTML сущности (PHP):

```
        $patterns = array(
    '#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#',
    '#\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]#',
    '#\[strike\](.*?)\[/strike\]#',
    '#\[em\](.*?)\[/em\]#',
    );

    $replacements = array(
    '<b>$1</b>',
    '<u>$1</u>',
    '<strike>$1</strike>',
    '<em>$1</em>',
    );

    $text = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы готовый текст обработанный при помощи данной функции, при попадании в `<textarea>`, изменялся обратно на BBCode?
То есть из `lol <b>text 123</b>` в текстарею должен попадать  `lol [b]text123[/b]`.

спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы использовал регулярное выражение просто и заменял по шаблону:
`/<(/?b)>/ig => "[$1]"`
Если не ошибаюсь, то так.

Пример:

```
var str = "<b>azaza</b> aza <b>kek</b> lool <B></B> dcs";
var n_str = str.replace(/<(\/?b)>/ig, "[$1]");
```

i в конце шаблона - любой регистр букв: b,B. Если нужно только b, i нужно убрать.
g в конце - значит, что нужно найти не первое совпадение, а все совпадения в строке.

Comment: а можете если вам не сложно составить полный код функции, просто я в этом плохо разбираюсь

Comment: спасибо, мне подошел ваш способ, но не могли бы вы подсказать как можно сделать из этого массив? а то у меня ещё <u> => [u] и тд, и приходится делать примитивно несколько строк

Comment: и ещё, совсем забыл, сделайте пожлауйста возможность захватывать текст если там есть пересоны, разрывы строк и тд, а то сейчас регулярка работает только на строку, спасибо

Comment: Не понял насчет массива, т.е. создать массив строк в каждой ячейке которого будет текст между тегами или как?
Чтобы работала не на одну строку: `/<(\/?b)>/igm`

Comment: я имею в виду что-то типа такого: <b> <em> <u> заменяем на [u|em|b] чтобы вообщем сократить строки

Comment: text = text.replace(/<(\/?strike)>/igm, "[$1]");
 text = text.replace(/<(\/?em)>/igm, "[$1]"); - вот как то так, объеденить такое в одну функцию